# Echo don't take indentation?

Tags: bash, shell, tabs, echo

I'm making a bash script, and I have a problem when I need to transfer lines to a `.sh` to another `.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line != "#" ]]; then
        echo -e "$line" >>save.sh
    fi
done
```

With this code I'm transfering lines but in my save.sh I don't have tab or spaces at all

```sh
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
echo "Error: not enough arguments"
exit 84
fi
```

I was wondering if anyone had any idea where it might come from.
I changed the echo to echo -e but nothing does, when i'm moving my lines to another files, the indentations is deleted.